# SharePoint Online - Trying to change page layouts of all pages of a publishing site through PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, page-layout

I am on SharePoint Online environment and am trying to change page layouts of all pages with in a Publishing site. By default the page layout is basic and am trying to change all pages to use a custom layout that I built. I am able to do so manually but I want to do it using PowerShell.

I am using this code on https://www.sharepointwidgets.com/2019/02/powershell-script-to-update-page-layout.html but I get a this error,

**Exception Happened on getAllPages :  + Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Url' because it is an empty string**.

Not really sure, why that's happening as I am passing the parameters
`[string]$targetSiteURL = Read-Host "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" [string]$newPageLayoutTitle = "Custom Page" [string]$oldPageLayoutTitle = "Basic Page"`

Please suggest or help with me with another solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint Online Modern page layouts:**

- Home Page Layout
- Article Page Layout
- Single Part App Page

**Please run the following PnP PowerShell script:**

```
Write-Host "Type the site collection URL:"
$siteCollectionURL = Read-Host
 
Write-Host "Type the page name:"
$PageName = Read-Host
 
Write-Host "Choose the page layout:"
        
Write-Host "1 - Home"
Write-Host "2 - Article"
Write-Host "3 - Single Web Part App Page"
$option = Read-Host
 
if($option -eq "1"){
    $option = "Home"
}elseif($option -eq "2"){
    $option = "Article"
}elseif($option -eq "3"){
    $option = "SingleWebPartAppPage"
}
 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteCollectionURL  
Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity $PageName -LayoutType $option
```

[image]